# 1-parametric subgroups of diffeomorphisms induce a complete vector field

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

I have been working through this [book](https://books.google.si/books?id=sI2bAxgLMXYC&redir_esc=y) on differential equations and I do not quite understand the justification for one claim. Namely, the author claims that every 1-parameter subgroup $\{\psi_\epsilon|\epsilon\in\mathbb{R}\}$ of diffeomorphisms gives rise to a vector field given by
$$ V(x) = \left.\frac{d}{d\epsilon}\right|_{\epsilon = 0}\psi_\epsilon(x).$$ I am having trouble seeing the justification for the use of derivative. Is every 1-parametric subgroup automatically smoothly dependent on the parameter? Or is there a smoothness assumption I am missing?